# Rails: insert associated column_id by looking up another column when importing from CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cvsimport

I looked at some issues here on StackOverflow and didn't find my case (which I think strange because my goal seems to be common enough).

I have two models: `Products` and `Categories` that are associated as follows:

- product `belongs_to :category`
- category `has_many :products`

Product has column `category_id`

CVS file has the following columns:

- product_name,
- category_name,
- product_price

How on Earth I can take `category_name` from the file and insert  `category_id` into the Products table?

I have the following code from Rails-Casts:

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Response.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything has to be done in one line. You can do something like this for each CSV row:

```
category_name = row['category_name']
category = Category.find_by_name(category_name) unless category_name.blank?

Product.create({
  name: row['product_name'],
  price: row['product_price'],
  category: category
))
```

Comment: You are AWESOME!!!! Thank you for your help! It wouldn't recognize my headers like that `row[:product_name]`, but it did work with indexes `row[0]`.  I'll look into it later :) Thanks again!!!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Use string keys for `row` unless you're passing a header converter that converts the header to a symbol, e.g. `headers: true, header_converters: :symbol` See "HeaderConverters" in https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html` for more information on this. Meanwhile, I updated the answer to use string keys.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much :)